# PySpark split using regex doesn't work on a dataframe column with string type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark data frame with a string column(URL) and all records look in the following way

```
ID                                   URL
1          https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2686735685
2          https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938415796
3          https://app.drift.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938419189
```

I want to basically extract the number after conversations/ from URL column using regex into another column.

I tried the following code but it doesn't give me any results.

```
df1 = df.withColumn('CONV_ID', split(convo_influ_new['URL'], '(?<=conversations/).*').getItem(0))
```

Expected:

```
ID                                   URL                                         CONV_ID
1          https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2686735685         2686735685
2          https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938415796         2938415796     
3          https://app.drift.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938419189       2938419189
```

Result:

```
ID                                   URL                                         CONV_ID
1          https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2686735685         https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2686735685
2          https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938415796         https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938415796     
3          https://app.drift.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938419189       https://app.drift.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938419189
```

Not sure what's happening here. I tried the regex script in different online regex tester toolds and it highlights the part I want but never works in PySpark. I tried different PySpark functions like `f.split`, `regexp_extract`, `regexp_replace`, but none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract` instead:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    'CONV_ID',
    F.regexp_extract('URL', 'conversations/(.*)', 1)
)

df1.show()
+---+--------------------+----------+
| ID|                 URL|   CONV_ID|
+---+--------------------+----------+
|  1|https://app.xyz.c...|2686735685|
|  2|https://app.xyz.c...|2938415796|
|  3|https://app.drift...|2938419189|
+---+--------------------+----------+
```

Or if you want to use `split`, you don't need to specify `.*`. You just need to specify the pattern used for splitting.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    'CONV_ID',
    F.split('URL', '(?<=conversations/)')[1]    # just using 'conversations/' should also be enough
)

df1.show()
+---+--------------------+----------+
| ID|                 URL|   CONV_ID|
+---+--------------------+----------+
|  1|https://app.xyz.c...|2686735685|
|  2|https://app.xyz.c...|2938415796|
|  3|https://app.drift...|2938419189|
+---+--------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are URLs have always that form, you can actually just use `substring_index` to get the last path element :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn("CONV_ID", F.substring_index("URL", "/", -1))

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
#|ID |URL                                                          |CONV_ID   |
#+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
#|1  |https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2686735685  |2686735685|
#|2  |https://app.xyz.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938415796  |2938415796|
#|3  |https://app.drift.com/inboxes/136636/conversations/2938419189|2938419189|
#+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```